# problems with currentlocation android googlemaps

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, kotlin

I'm having difficulties for vienna to take the current location, someone could guide me, the value of vienna is static can only be defined, I wanted you to take the current location. could someone help me, thanks. any help is welcome

Utils code

```
import map.me.models.Issue
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

class Utils (location: LatLng){
    companion object {
        lateinit var currentLocation: LatLng
        var vienna= LatLng(-23.5629, -46.6544)
        var markers = ArrayList<Issue>()
    }

    init {
        vienna = LatLng(-23.5629, -46.6544)
        currentLocation = location
        markers = ArrayList()
    }
}
```

code mapfrag

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        Log.i("MAP READY", "READY")
        val position = if (currentLocation != null) LatLng(currentLocation!!.latitude, currentLocation!!.longitude) else Utils.vienna
        this.map = googleMap
        this.map!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15f)) // Vienna
        getFineLocationPermission()
        this.map!!.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
        this.map!!.uiSettings.isRotateGesturesEnabled = true
        this.map!!.uiSettings.isZoomGesturesEnabled = true
        this.map!!.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this)
        this.map!!.setOnMapLongClickListener(this)


    }
```

Comment: How you request location?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Good when creating the marker manually by clicking on the map he can get the current location, but when he clicks a button for quick dialing he gets utils.vienna and I need to modify utils.vienna to use currentlocation the problem that in all the ways I tried making mistakes occurs.

Comment: Since you have `currentLocation` variable, when you click new location on map you need to modify its value. [So you get location in map when user click at some location not from GPS?]

Comment: val position = if (currentLocation != null) LatLng(currentLocation!!.latitude, currentLocation!!.longitude) else Utils.currentLocation give this error kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property currentLocation has not been initialized

Comment: i'm update post for more informations

Comment: Please wait for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about your initialized your utils class firts?
so you will not got `error kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property currentLocation`

```
class Utils (){
companion object {
    lateinit var currentLocation: LatLng
    var vienna= LatLng(-23.5629, -46.6544)
    var markers = ArrayList<Issue>()
}

fun initMyCurrentLocation(loc:LatLang?){
    currentLocation = loc?: vienna
  }
}
```

in your frag you can used this method like this:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
//init you currentLocationHere
Utils.initMyCurrentLocation('yourCurrentLocation')
//the rest code.
  val position = if (currentLocation != null) LatLng(currentLocation!!.latitude, currentLocation!!.longitude) else Utils.vienna
    this.map = googleMap
    this.map!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 15f)) // Vienna
    getFineLocationPermission()
    this.map!!.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
    this.map!!.uiSettings.isRotateGesturesEnabled = true
    this.map!!.uiSettings.isZoomGesturesEnabled = true
    this.map!!.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this)
    this.map!!.setOnMapLongClickListener(this)


}
```

Comment: could you guide me how to start utils? I would be very grateful. for the help. I'm new

Comment: you can try like that.
if you want to use code.
I recommended you learn about Singleton.

Comment: Classifier 'LatLng' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here in utils

Comment: hi yes i'm giving error my code. val position: LatLng = if (currentLocation != null) LatLng(currentLocation!!.latitude, currentLocation!!.longitude) else Utils.initMyCurrentLocation(
            loc = LatLng?)

Comment: Classifier 'LatLng' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Comment: @YPLABS already add some more detail to code. you can check the answer.

Comment: in 'your Current Location') I put what?

Comment: you put your current location, you got from map location.
read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/current-place-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property currentLocation has not been initialized
```

That happen because your `lateinit var currentLocation: LatLng` never initialize in `init{}` block. `init{}` block for class will call when you create new Instance of that class. But your `currentLocation`is a variable in `companion object`, so when you call it that way your class is never created an object and `currentLocation` will never initialized.

You can fix this by using object instead of class.

```
object Utils  {
    lateinit var currentLocation: LatLng
    init {
         currentLocation = `...`
    }

}
```